# Symfony2 functional test authentication

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to set my functional tests up and I'm having problems with getting authenticated. I've read over this guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html and implemented what they have said to do but I still get stuck on redirecting login. I'm sure this is something trivial but I'm not sure what.

**Test Controller**

```
namespace HvH\ClientsBundle\Tests\Controller;

use HvH\ClientsBundle\Controller\ClientsController;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ClientsControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testGetClientsAction()
    {

        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request(
           '/clients/123456', 
           'GET', 
            array(), /* request params */ 
            array(), /* files */
            array('X-Requested-With' => "XMLHttpRequest", 'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'testuser', 'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'testpass')
        );

        print_r($client->getResponse());
        die();
    }
}
```

**congif_test.yml**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            http_basic:
```

**Result of the request**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse Object
(
    [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
        (
            [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                    [no-cache] => 1
                )

            [cookies:protected] => Array
                (
                    [] => Array
                        (
                            [/] => Array
                                (
                                    [PHPSESSID] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie Object
                                        (
                                            [name:protected] => PHPSESSID
                                            [value:protected] => 7e3ece541918264de0003e2dcd251833
                                            [domain:protected] => 
                                            [expire:protected] => 1342616045
                                            [path:protected] => /
                                            [secure:protected] => 
                                            [httpOnly:protected] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://localhost/login
                        )

                    [cache-control] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => no-cache
                        )

                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Wed, 18 Jul 2012 00:54:05 GMT
                        )

                    [content-type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => text/html
                        )

                    [x-debug-token] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5006092d43848
                        )

                )

            [cacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [content:protected] => <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/login">http://localhost/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
    [version:protected] => 1.0
    [statusCode:protected] => 302
    [statusText:protected] => Found
    [charset:protected] => UTF-8
)
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: If your are using FOSUserBundle, please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957807/symfony2-tests-with-fosuserbundle/27223293#27223293

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to do the following:

1) 'browse' to the page

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
```

2) Select the form via the submit button

```
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('submit');
```

3) Pass the login credentials as data and submit the form

```
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
$data = array('username' => 'u@u.com','password' => 'pass');
$client->submit($form,$data);
```

4) Follow the redirect

```
$crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```

5) At this point you should be able to check the response code

```
$this->assertEquals(302, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

or access a secured page

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/dashboard');
//do other stuff
```

Answer (score 8):

Either use:

```
$crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```

or make that client always redirects:

```
$client->followRedirects();
```

Related doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#redirecting

Comment: Thanks. That seems to get me to the login page, how do I get it to authenticate?

Comment: I guess I could create a method for the crawler to simulate the login, but ideally it could just work with the PHP_AUTH vars

Comment: Have you tried this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html

Comment: The order you pass the parameters seems to be wrong, look here: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.html#method_request